# How can I cast NextJS router.query as a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
const router = useRouter()
const { photoId } = router.query
```

I get this Typescript warning when doing a comparison:

> TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types
> 'number' and 'string | string[]' have no overlap.

This makes perfect sense, so I typecast my variable like this:

```
const router = useRouter()
const { photoId } = parseInt(router.query, 10)
```

But now I get this warning:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'ParsedUrlQuery' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'string'.

When I look at the source code for NextJS router, I see this:

```
interface ParsedUrlQuery extends NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]> { }
```

Which looks like I'm pretty close to getting what I need, which is just a string instead of a string or array of strings. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can tell compiler how the variable should be treated:

```
const photoId = parseInt(router.query.photoId as string, 10)
```

Note that attributes of `router.query` can be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing this with a small variation to pass ESLint: parseInt(router.query.photoId as any as string, 10)

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be doing a casting in this way:

```
const photoId = router.query.photoId ? +router.query.photoId : undefined;
```

Query props might be undefined, so you first check if it's defined, the use the unary operator, or just return the `undefined`. The type of `integer` would be `number | undefined`. Of course, keep in mind if the `photoId` is value that can be converted to number.

I always try to refrain from using `as` as typescript is already unsound, so this isn't adding an extra "trustiness" to the type system itself.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, `router.query()` is `ParsedUrlQuery` object. We can extend the interface and thereby add path / query parameters we expect to receive. In your case you can do the following

```
interface ParsedUrlQueryForPage extends ParsedUrlQuery {
    photoId: number
}
```

Then, you can assert the type of `router.query` this way

```
const { photoId } = router.query as ParsedUrlQueryForPage
```

An alternative to using interface extension is intersection type

```
const { photoId } = router.query as ParsedUrlQuery & { photoId : number }
```

You can refer to this article for more details
https://reacthustle.com/blog/parse-nextjs-query-params-typescript

You can read more about intersection types and the difference with interface extension in the TypeScript documentation.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest using typescript predicates rather than casting `as string` directly. This can be used more generally to guarantee `router.query` produces type safe results. It's a bit more verbose but the below strategy helps to ensure type safety better than casting:

```js
type ExpectedQuery = {
  photoId: string;
}

function isValidQuery(query: ParsedUrlQuery): query is ExpectedQuery {
  // check the query properties
  return typeof (query.photoId) === 'string'
}

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (!isValidQuery(router.query)) {
    // the query isn't what you expected
    // handle it somehow
    return null;
  }

  // Cast to number/undefined
  let photoId = +router.query.photoId

  // Check that it cast correctly
  if (!photoId || isNaN(photoId)) {
    // handle undefined or NaN case
    return null
  }

  // Do stuff with photoId (it's a number so you can do number-like-things)
  photoId += 10;

  return <div>{photoId}</div>
}
```

Comment: @YuminGui You should elaborate on your comment. Telling someone their code isn't clean without explaining the faults of their code doesn't help them or anybody else reading.

Comment: What does the + in front of `let photoId = +router.query.photoId` mean? Is it a shorthand typecasting for`Number()`?

Comment: @sayandcode yep.

Comment: @YuminGui hey, thanks for the feedback. I had to think about it a bit and I can see where you're coming from. I was concerned about type safety issues in my response and after learning more I'm seeing that casting `as string` is not a terrible way to do this if you have some confidence in the type coming back. However, the solution I provided will guarantee that the variable is a string if you have any doubts.