# Property 'X' is missing in type 'Dict<string | string[]>' but required in type 'Query'

Tags: next.js

What is wrong here?

```js
interface Query {
    userId: string
}

function ConfirmEmail(props: ConfirmEmailProps) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { userId } = router.query as Query // <-- error here
    useEffect(() => {
        let data = { userId: userId }
        axios
            .post(`confirmEmail`, data)
            .then((resp) =>
                setTimeout(() => {
                    redirectToHome()
                }, 3000)
            )
            .catch((err) => console.error(err))
    })
```

though here it work, no error raised, same patttern I use:

```
interface MyTicketListProps {}
interface Query {
    [key: string]: string | string[]
    paymentId: string
}
export default function MyTicketList(props: MyTicketListProps) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const { paymentId } = router.query as Query
```

First case file has [] around, does it matter maybe?
`pages/confirmEmail/[userId]`

Second case does not have [] around.

Answer (score 0):

I think in you have to write your code like this ...

```
const { userId } = router.query as NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]>
```

for more details see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692699/how-can-i-cast-nextjs-router-query-as-a-number)